# How can I get count for a particular term from lucene index 2.2

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-stack

I am working on term hit report where I have to find overall term count in lucene index. But every time I am getting different count for one term. Any one have idea on this like how to get term count from lucene index. I am okay with lucene 4.4 and 2.2 both.

Comment: are you using elasticsearch for this task ? if yes, can you please post the sample mapping and the query which you are using as well ?

Comment: I'm just creating a lucene index and then just trying to get a term frequency from that index. No elastic search as of now.